# Swift UICollectionView Cell favourite button after scrolling changed to unfavorite

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

`UICollectionView` Cell I am showing product with favourite and unfavourite options in single button, It is located in `collectionview cell`. whenever I am scrolling the `UICollectionview` cell favourite automatically changed to unfavourite. How to solve this issues?

Comment: Show the code you are using to control the favorite.

Comment: Sure I will post @MwcsMac